# Azure Cloud Service and AfterBuild Target Access Denied

Tags: azure, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm trying to combine several html files into one when publishing to Cloud Azure, I added the following to the .csproj files

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CreateItem Include="$(ProjectDir)js\ordering-widget\tpl\*.html">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="htmlFilesToCombine" />
    </CreateItem>

    <ReadLinesFromFile File="%(htmlFilesToCombine.FullPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="htmlLines" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(ProjectDir)js\ordering-widget\tpl\combined.html" Lines="@(htmlLines)" Overwrite="true" /> 
  </Target>
```

However, Im getting an access denied error

```
$/Allegro Web/Allegro Web/Allegro Web.sln ('Allegro Web:Publish' target(s)) - 1 error(s), 1 warning(s),View log file
C:\a\src\Allegro Web\MvcWebRoleCore\MvcWebRoleCore.csproj (983): Could not write lines to file "C:\a\src\Allegro Web\MvcWebRoleCore\js\ordering-widget\tpl\combined.html". Access to the path 'C:\a\src\Allegro Web\MvcWebRoleCore\js\ordering-widget\tpl\combined.html' is denied.
```

It's an azure permission error apparently, how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you publishing to Azure Websites or an Azure web role?

Comment: @IUnknown Azure Cloud Services, Azure Web Role

Comment: I haven't had time to see exactly what the directory macros are for tfsbuild, but I found that I could write to the c:\a\bin directory fine - but not the c:\a\src directory.  Try using $(TargetDir) instead or something derived from $(OutDir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to azure projects directly.

This is due to the file being read only on disk.  You will need to add a step in your script that does and attrib -r on the file you are trying to write.